# Does Job Rerun on Control-M alter the Job Command?

Tags: control-m

I need to know if rerunning a job in Control-M using 'Rerun' option alter the Job Command? If not so, how to induce it so that the job receives a different set of parameters on rerun.

Example for Commands for the job in Control-M:

simple run: `sh run_my_job.sh <arg1>`

rerun: `sh run_my_job.sh  RESTART <arg1>`

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't. You can try this:

Job: check the runcount & determine whether its a rerun.
     Invoke job 2 if its a rerun. 
Else simple run.
Job2: Rerun command